# How to associate values from a python dict to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
data = {'A':['a','a',3,3,'c','c'],'B': [0, .5, 101, 105, 2000, 2500]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A','B'])
```

and a dictionary

```
d = {'a':['a',3,'c'],'b':[5,200,3000],'c':[1,2,3]}
```

I would like to use `d['a']` to compare with `df['A']` and if equal to add the value from `d['b']` to `df['B']` in to a new column `df['C']` that the result would be

```
data2 = {'A':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],'B': [0, .5, 101, 105, 2000, 2500],'C':[5,5.5,301,305,5000,5500]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['A','B','C'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative would be to construct an ordinary map:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A':['a','a',3,3,'c','c','d'],'B': [0, .5, 101, 105, 2000, 2500, 3000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A','B'])

m = dict(zip(d['a'],d['b']))
df['C'] = df['B'] + df['A'].map(m).fillna(0)  # Fillna to avoid Not A Number (NaN

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   A       B       C
0  a     0.0     5.0
1  a     0.5     5.5
2  3   101.0   301.0
3  3   105.0   305.0
4  c  2000.0  5000.0
5  c  2500.0  5500.0
6  d  3000.0  3000.0
```

Comment: Nice, far better than mine! Still don't understand how OP updates `df['A']`.